# Python: tensorflow установлен, но не найден модуль

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels)=fashion_mnist.load_data()
class_names=['T-shirt/top','Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

train_images.shape
test_images.shape
len(train_labels)
len(test_labels)
train_labels

train_images = train_images/255.0
test_images = test_images /255.0

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for i in range(25):
    plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(train_images[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xlabel(class_names[train_labels[i]])

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
              loss='space_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
print('Test accuracy: ', test_acc)

predictions = model.predict(test_images)

np.argmax(predictions[0]) #9
test_labels[0]#9


def plot_image(i, predictions_array, true_label, img):
    predictions_array, true_label, img = predictions_array[i], true_label[i], img[i]
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])


    plt.imshow(img,cmap=plt.cm.binary)

    predicted_label = np.argmax(predictions_array)
    if predicted_label==true_label :
        color='blue'
    else:
        color='red'
    plt.xlabel("{}{:2.0f}% ({})").format(class_names[predicted_label],
                                         100*np.max(predictions_array),
                                         class_names[true_label],
                                         color=color)

def plot_value_array(i, predictions_array, true_label):
    prediction_array, true_label = predictions_array[i], true_label[i]
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    thisplot=plt.bar(range(10), predictions_array, color="#777777")
    plt.ylim([0,1])
    predicted_label=np.argmax(predictions_array)

    thisplot[predicted_label].set_color('red')
    thisplot[true_label].set_color('blue')

    num_rows = 5
    num_cols = 3
    num_images = num_rows * num_cols
    plt.figure(figsize=(2 * 2 * num_cols, 2 * num_rows))
    for i in range(num_images):
        plt.subplot(num_rows, 2 * num_cols, 2 * i + 1)
        plot_image(i, predictions, test_labels, test_images)
        plt.subplot(num_rows, 2 * num_cols, 2 * i + 2)
        plot_value_array(i, predictions, test_labels)


img = test_images[0]
img = (np.expand_dims (img, 0))

predictions_single = model.predict(img)
print(predictions_single)
```

ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Comment: пробовали `pip install --upgrade tensorflow`?

Comment: Видимо, это Windows, а там с установкой библиотек довольно много разных приколов.